# Efficient way to get the index of the first 2 consecutive 1-bit

Tags: c, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have this binary representation:
`0b0110010`

With gcc, there is the built-in function `__builtin_ffs` that will return one plus the index of the least significant 1-bit, which returns 2 for my example.

I'm searching for a efficient way to return the index of 2 consecutive 1-bit, which would be 5 for my example.
The language is C and and I have 64 bits numbers * 1024 to check. Would be great if the solution can cover the case of N consecutive bits too.

The simple solution would be to iterate through the bits with right shift operation and use a mask but it's not efficient.

Comment: How large are the numbers you are trying t check? If they are not too large, let's say 8 bit or maybe 16 bit you could implement a LUT.

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::bitset` and C doesn't.

Comment: Left shift 1 bit, `and` with the original, then do what `__bultin_ffs` does

Comment: @WeijunZhou that's worth an answer.

Comment: `std::bitset` is pointless anyway, but C++20 also has `std::countr_zero` which is actually useful (similar to `__builtin_ffs` but `std::countr_zero` returns the actual index whereas `__builtin_ffs` returns the index plus one, also the behaviour differs if the input is zero)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since gcc already have the built in, one way to do it is to right shift the number by one bit, bitwise `and` with the original, then forward the work to `__builtin_ffs`, i.e.

```
__builtin_ffs((x >> 1) & x)
```

Note this uses compiler intrinsics and is by definition not portable.

On architectures like x86, there are built in assembly instructions for bit scan (`bsf`). A hand-written C implementation is unlikely to perform better than that.